# Visual Studio Code error: Git not found. Install it or configure it using the "git.path" setting Mac Sonoma 14.1

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I recently switched to a new Mac laptop and I installed git, confirmed the version and the path, and every time I open a directory in VS Code I get this error:

`Git not found. Install it or configure it using the "git.path" setting.`

I went into the user.json settings and pasted my path and restarted both VS Code and my computer. The error won't go away.  In the meantime, I am able to push code to remote repos and everything appears to be working.

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark Modern",


// enable Git in VS Code
"git.enabled": true,

// point to the Git executable
"git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git"
}
```

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: please edit your question: how exactly did you install git? What is the output of `git --version`?

Comment: Is there a way to tell what previous version of git I had?  I didn't mean to not provide enough info.  I believe I used the binary installer for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with my version of git.  When I checked it said something like 2.39 [Apple].  I ended up downloading Homebrew and installing the most current version of git and all is now well.